# How to Get the "templateLocation" parameter value of an existing Job in google dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a list of an existing jobs running in a google dataflow. I would like to list the jobs running for last x number of days and would like to recycle those programmatically. To achieve this I need the name of the template used for a particular job. We can easily get this information from Console in a Job Info view. However i would like to know if there is any way to get this info from Gcloud command or from a API.

Your early response will be appreciated.

Thanks
Sarang

Answer (score 1):

**- Solution 1 :**

You can use `GCloud sdk` and a `shell` script to achieve your need :

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/list

Filter jobs with the given name:

```bash
gcloud dataflow jobs list --filter="name=my-wordcount"
```

List jobs with from a given region:

```bash
gcloud dataflow jobs list --region="europe-west1"
```

List jobs created this year:

```bash
gcloud dataflow jobs list --created-after=2018-01-01
```

List jobs created more than a week ago:

```bash
gcloud dataflow jobs list --created-before=-P1W
```

Many filters and parameters are proposed to apply your use case.

**- Solution 2**

You can use the `rest` api for `Dataflow` jobs :

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest

Example :

```
GET /v1b3/projects/{projectId}/locations/{location}/jobs
List the jobs of a project.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However i want to drilldown one layer below the job name. Your solution can give me the job list and i am interested in knowing the template used for that job.

Comment: And with this `api` call ? : 
GET /v1b3/projects/{projectId}/locations/{location}/templates:get
Get the template associated with a template.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of getting the template location and name. To achieve above requirement I have defined the pattern for the template name and job name and based on the defined pattern, while recycling the job, template name has been computed and passed on to the API call.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).